# Difference between ETA and On-Block time?

Tags: air-traffic-control, landing, airport, time

I see that the definition of the ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival) according to [Eurocontrol](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Estimated_Time_of_Arrival) is:

> 1. (SESAR) the time computed by the FMS for the flight arriving at a point related to the destination airport
> 2. (ICAO) For IFR flights, the time at which it is estimated that the aircraft will arrive over that designated point, defined by reference to navigation aids, from which it is intended that an instrument approach procedure will be commenced, or, if no navigation aid is associated with the aerodrome, the time at which the aircraft will arrive over the aerodrome.
>
> For VFR flights, the time at which it is estimated that the aircraft will arrive over the aerodrome.

However I do not understand what is the difference with the Estimated On-Block time.
Would you be able to explain the difference please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eurocontrol Lexicon can help here as well. The **Estimated In-Block Time** is defined as:

> The estimated time that an aircraft will arrive in-block.

<sup>([Eurocontrol](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Estimated_In-Block_Time))</sup>

This is not very helpful, but the definition for **Actual In-Block Time** is:

> The actual date and time when the parking brakes have been engaged at the parking position.

<sup>([Eurocontrol](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Actual_In-Block_Time))</sup>

This time is relevant for gate availability because the aircraft is expected to be at its gate (or remote parking position) at this time.

The **Estimated Time of Arrival** is, as your quote says, a time where the aircraft is still in the air. This is relevant for Air Traffic Control because the number of aircraft that can fly an instrument approach to the destination airport at the same time is limited. If too many aircraft have a similar estimated time of arrival, some will have to hold in a pattern or are delayed on-route already.